# Add subview to a xib file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

I'm trying to add a label to a UIView in a xib file. When I run the app, the label doesn't shows up.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 200)];
    [self.label setText:@"This is a label"];

    xibView *myxibView = [[xibView alloc] init];
    [myxibView.myView addSubview:self.label];
}
```

Comment: You created a local instance of xibView, you didn't added it to anywhere and not showing that view. So how can you expect that to show the label ?

Comment: The xib is a custom cell. I'm trying to add a label programmatically

Comment: A simple example: You put bread (xibView) on your home (Storyboard). Now you are at your office (viewDidLoad), you bought a new bread (created a new instance of xibView) and put honey on it (Label). Now you are saying that you can't see honey on the bread you left at home. I hope you understand.

Comment: So how can I change that?

Comment: Connect an outlet to the existing xibView in the storyboard and use it.

Comment: I've previously tried that, but the problem was that I cannot get the labels height from the xibView.m file to the mainVIewController.m. When I do that, it gives me a height of 0

Comment: That's because the view is not loaded yet. Try that in viewWillAppear. Also you connected the outlet or not

Comment: didn't work. Still don't see the label

Comment: You are adding that label to your outlet right ? And you are not allocating it again, right ?

Comment: I'm adding the label to myView which is a IBOutlet in the xib file. Allocating what again?

Comment: Can you add your new code or can you share a sample app ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: Whos the file owner of the XIB? is it thew view controller? or the custom view class you made?

Comment: customView class I think... I made a new UITableViewCell file, and I checked off add xib to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.If your controller has the same name with your xib,
For example,XibViewController.m & XibViewController.xib.
Your controller will set its view to an instance of XibViewController.xib by default.

On this condition, you just need to add the label to the self.view

```
[self.view addSubview:self.label];
```

2.If you want to load the XibViewController.xib to an different name controller like View2Controller.m,  you need load the xib by name and and add the xib view to View2Controller's view.

```
UIView *myxibView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"XibViewController" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[myxibView addSubview:self.label];
[self.view addSubview:myxibView];
```

Comment: I think this answer is self-explanatory and has to be *accepted*

Answer (score 0):

```
xibView *myxibView = [[xibView alloc] init];
[myxibView.myView addSubview:self.label];
```

You didn't added myxibView to actual view. Its just an instance. Why don't you do this:

```
 [self.view addSubview:self.label];
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: The xib has a view called myView which I placed in the storyBoard. And the xib is a custom cell. I'm trying to add a label programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Simply add ,

```
self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 200)];
[self.label setText:@"This is a label"];
[self.view addSubview:self.label];
```

It will subView the label on the view.