# Programmatically add an object to a xib file through another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xib

I have a .m and .h file linked to a xib called cusomxib. In the xib I added a UIView.

How can I programmatically add a label to myVIew  (from the xib file) through another class? It won't work to create a new instance of the xib file as shown below because it will create a new one. I want to access the original one.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 200)];
    [self.label setText:@"This is a label"];

    xibView *myxibView = [[xibView alloc] init]; // This is the part thats wrong. I need to use something that just gets the file, not create a new one.
    [myxibView.myView addSubview:self.label];
}
```

Hope this is clear enough. If you need me to clarify something, I'd be happy to.

Comment: didnt you just ask this question? rather update your previous question with this new info

Comment: you again asked the same question , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28289999/add-subview-to-a-xib-file

Comment: what you meant by ' xib storyboard ' ?

Comment: I meant xib, will update the question. Thanks for the notification

Comment: @MikeRally: you want to subview label in the same viewController right ?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 200)];
    [self.label setText:@"This is a label"];
    [self.view addSubview:self.label];
}
```

Comment: Where are you telling me to place this?

Comment: I don't want the label to be as a subview of the main viewController, I want it as a subview of a view in the xib

Comment: @MikeRally: I couldn't understand what you are saying. Do you want to create a SubClass of a UIVIew ?